# Mercurial not ignoring files

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I've tried multiple ways to block a folder of logs from Mercurial but it continues to be seen by `hg status`.  I have other ignore commands that are being obeyed, but this folder for some reason won't be ignored.  I've tried...

```
syntax: glob
sitename/system/logs
```

`regexp:^sitename/system/logs$`

`glob:sitename/system/logs`

Despite all of these methods in place I continue to see the following in `hg status`

```
M sitename/system/logs/log-2010-11-03.php
M sitename/system/logs/log-2010-11-04.php
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The problem is you added the file. That's why you see an `M`. Stop tracking the file, and then your ignore will work.

Comment: I just removed the file and committed.  I've verified that the changes were committed, but `hg status` still shows ! next to all the log files...

Comment: @Webnet: You need to `hg remove`, not just delete the file. `!` means Mercurial thinks the file is missing.